# Outlook Reminders not working for one Exchange Account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

the problem I am facing is this:

A few Users have a Exchange-Mailbox("Purchasing") connected to their Outlook, together with their personal Mailbox.

However one User(1) does not get Outlook-Reminders from that "Purchasing"-Mailbox while they do get the reminders from their personal mailbox.

Every other User(2), for whom I have set up the "Purchasing"-Mailbox in the exact same way, does get the reminders.

If the User(1) sets a task with reminder on a message in the "Purchasing"-Mailbox, they themself dont get a reminder, but other Users(2) do get it.

Reminders in this case are both from calendar dates and from tasks.

Are there any settings that could cause such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the "Purchasing"-Mailbox is a shared mailbox, right? Is it added as a separate account via **File > Add Account**?

In case it's an issue with the current outlook profile of User(1), try creating a new Outlook profile and add the "Purchasing"-Mailbox first. If the reminders in the "Purchasing"-Mailbox can pop up properly, then add the user's personal mailbox and check if everything can work fine.

For instructions about how to create new Outlook profile and switch between different Outlook profiles, see [Overview of Outlook e-mail profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-outlook-e-mail-profiles-9073a8ac-c3d6-421d-b5b9-fcedff7642fc) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, it was added as a separate account.
I did as you advised and, with the new profile, it seems to work now. I can't give you a +1(no reputation) but I'll mark this as the answer.
Thanks.